# Fast Plotting in MSCharts with C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, mschart

I need to update a FastLine plot in a MS Chart using C# **every 1 ms**. I have two arrays of 2048 elements, one for the X values (`xValue`) and one for the Y values (`yValue`). At the moment I am doing it like this:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
{
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(xValue[i], yValue[i]);
}
```

The problem is that this is very slow (5% of the speed I need)...

***How can I do it in a faster, more efficient way?***

Comment: Considering common displays are 60 Hz > 16 ms / frame, it wouldn't make much sense to update the chart every 1 ms. Regardless, I doubt you'll be able to get the performance you're asking for using MS Chart in C#/.NET.

Comment: Yes, it makes a difference because it does not matter if I don't see the data at that frequency but I need to program to continue the data acquisition at 1 KHz... Thanks

Comment: Is it not possible to acquire and process the data at 1 KHz yet render and display it at 60Hz?

Comment: Yes, but still is very slow....My questions, is there  a more efficient way of plotting an array of X and Y than using AddXY() ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this:

```
    // initialize a connection string   
    string myConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileNameString;

    // define the database query    
    string mySelectQuery="SELECT Name, Sales FROM REPS WHERE RegionID < 3;";

    // create a database connection object using the connection string  
    OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(myConnectionString);

    // create a database command on the connection using query  
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection);

    // open the connection  
    myCommand.Connection.Open();

    // create a database reader 
    OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    // since the reader implements and IEnumerable, pass the reader directly into
    // the DataBind method with the name of the Column selected in the query    
    Chart1.Series["Default"].Points.DataBindXY(myReader, "Name", myReader, "Sales");
```

This is taken directly from the MSChart project in the DatabaseBindingXY.cs.
It might be faster than looping through the set of data.

I suggest that you download the [Samples Environments for Microsoft Chart Controls](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61)

Comment: I wish I could give you +100 for mentioning the Samples Environments for Microsoft Chart Controls.... Thank you, Thank you SO MUCH!